# Hibernate is eagerly fetching OneToOne relationships despite FetchType.LAZY annotation

Tags: hibernate

I have annotated entities for lazy fetching but hibernate is eagerly fetching OneToOne relationships.  It cascades this behavior to the fetched table.

I read somewhere that this is the default behavior for OneToOne relationships, but I have explicitly specified a fetch strategy of FetchType.LAZY

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="fcItemMast")
public FcQueue getFcQueue() {
    return this.fcQueue;
}

public void setFcQueue(FcQueue fcQueue) {
    this.fcQueue = fcQueue;
}
```

This is my biggest issue at this time.  I have no idea why an insert into a global temporary table followed by and immediate fetch results in no rows in the table despite the fact that I can see the insert statement after my "flush" and the fact that there is nothing wrong with the code as demonstrated by just making the table not a temporary table (Oracle 18).

Comment: Horribly written jboss page with an invalid certificate.  

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SomeExplanationsOnLazyLoadingone-to-one

This seems intentional, I don't understand why.   

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1001116

Comment: user939857 put here you entities and table scripts and snippets of code where you flash